# What is the best way to display Salesforce Data on a Wordpress website?

Tags: images, website-integration, wordpress

I want to be able to generate content driven webpages on my corporate website - populated with data that is in Salesforce.  My website is built on WordPress and my content include various field values - including images.

I have profiles of work done stored in a custom object in Salesforce.  These records contain fields such as Project Name, Product Description, Project Date, Project Location and I have a few photo fields.  Each profile also has a 'Display Online" checkbox.  When I check the 'Display Online" check box, I want that information to be displayed on a Project Profile page on my website.

I did this at a previous company but had to integrated with OrchestraCMS to do it.  As that was 7 years ago, I am hoping I can do it without using OrchestraCMS.

Can this be done in Communities?  If so, and directions/instructions/tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main purposes of communities is exactly the thing that you need. 
Integrating WP to show info from SF in my opinion is not a good approach in my opinion.

You can start with a trail of course https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/communities

Pay attention to the security settings and how to give the access to the account object.

Combining the out of the box lightning components from the community builder and the Lightning component in which you may embed screen flow covers a lot of use cases. I would recommend looking into them on Trailhead